# Mobile Theme user agent not working in safari ipad and ipad pro screens

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

We are using Magento 2.4.3 p2.

The mobile menu is not working on iPad screens in the safari version, but it is working when i check in the chrome developer tool iPad screens.

Useragent i added in the adminpanel:

/iPhone|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini|iPad|iPod/

[image]
Ex: safari browser iPad(8th generation)

Is there any other useragent rule needs to be added for safari ipad screens? Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent

Comment: @MagePalExtensions It's not answering working solutions in the above link. Anyway, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Based on a quick 5 minutes review, it seems like it is not possible because Apple now sends ``Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15)..`` as the useragent.